# v-model modifier returns empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

Referring to [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#handling-v-model-modifiers) link, and as stated in the following code:

```
<hello-world v-model="refInputModel"
             v-model:firstName.capitalize="refInputModel2"/>
```

i am using the `v-model-modifiers` `capitalize`

at run time, when `onUpdated` in `HelloWorld` is called, the value of `console.log("modelModifiers:",props.modelModifiers);` is empty!!
i expected to see `{ capitalize: true }` as a result, as stated in the forementioned link

please let me know why `props.model-modifiers` is empty and how to correct it

**App**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <div>
      <button @click="counterFunc">methodHandler</button>
      
      <hello-world v-model="refInputModel"
               v-model:firstName.capitalize="refInputModel2"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {ref,defineProps} from 'vue' 

const props = defineProps(['inputModel_','inputModel_2'])
let refInputModel = ref(props.inputModel_)
let refInputModel2 = ref(props.inputModel_2)

const counterFunc = ()=> {
  refInputModel.value = "changed"
  refInputModel2.value = "changed2"
}
</script>
```

**HelloWorld**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
  <input :value="modelValue"
         @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"/>
   
  <input :value="firstName"
         @input="$emit('update:firstName', $event.target.value)"/>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import { onUpdated,defineProps,defineEmits} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue:String,
  firstName:String,
  modelModifiers: { default: () => ({}) }
})
defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'update:firstName'])

onUpdated(()=>{
  console.log("HelloWorld.onUpdated");
  console.log("modelValue:",props.modelValue);
  console.log("modefirstNamelValue:",props.firstName);
  console.log("modelModifiers:",props.modelModifiers);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `firstNameModifiers` if you want to get modifiers for the `:firstName` prop.
Have a look at the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#handling-v-model-modifiers):

> For v-model bindings with both argument and modifiers, the generated prop name will be `arg + "Modifiers`